# Dismiss iOS native MPVolumeView audio route menu

Tags: ios, mpvolumeview

I'm using MPVolumeView to allow the user to control his preferred audio route when using my application.

The view is presented by this code:

```
self.volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
self.volumeView.showsVolumeSlider = NO;
[self.view addSubview:self.volumeView];
```

When the user taps the audio route button a menu appears with the available options.

The issue: The screen that shows the volume view, might need to be hidden because of various events my application handles and I would like to hide the audio route menu at the same time (if it's currently presented)

My question:
Does anybody know if it's possible to manually dismiss MPVolumeView's audio route selection menu without the user having to press the cancel button?

Thanks!

Comment: hey did you got answer, actully i m in same problem.

Answer (score 0):

on iOS 8, you can use below code which use private API

```
            NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
    for (UIWindow *window in windows) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([window class]) isEqualToString:@"_MPAVRoutingSheetSecureWindow"]) {
            UIView *view = [window.subviews firstObject];
            if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"MPAVRoutingSheet"]) {
                [view performSelector:@selector(dismiss)];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Even though it solves the problem, it's usually not a good practice to suggest usage of private API...